# How to run "ng xi18n" command for separated apps by Multi-App project?

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-cli

I do have a multi apps Project.

`/src
   /app1
      /...
   /app2
      /...`

And I have for `app1` already generated translation files `i18n` which are saved in assets folder... generating them was based on the keys in the HTML files in app1 :

`/assets
    /app1
       /i18n
    /app2`

Now I would like to generate separated `i18n` files for app2. 
So, when I run following command: `ng xi18n --app app2 --output-path assets/i18n`, it generates files and also output them in the correct folder.

But the issue is, that it doesn't generate files from and for `app2`. It generate files from and for 'app1'.

Is there a way how to generate the translation files for specific app in this case?

Comment: Have you defined an `app2` in the *angular-cli.json* file under `apps`?

Comment: Yes, sure. And also the `/dist`output folder has been specified separately. e.g. `"outDir": "dist/app1",` and `"outDir": "dist/app2",` and it works straightforward when running `build` for production

Answer (score 1):

this works (tested with Angular 8 & CLI v8):

```
ng xi18n --output-path src/locale --project=app2
```